# Seting the PATH environment variable via cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables

I tried to add to the PATH environment variable ";C:\my_EXE" so I can run the programs I put there via cmd (windows 8).
I tried this command:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\my_EXE
```

but it changed the PATH environment variable only until the CMD window was closed.
I searched on Google and I found this command:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\my_EXE"
```

that is supposed to set it forever, but it also works only until the CMD window has closed
and it made something like this:

```
[new PATH]=[old PATH]X2
```

It appears only in a new cmd and not in system properties(!=cmd, there is the PATH with my new path and not X2)

Why does this happen?
How can I set the PATH environment variable without problems?

Comment: There are two persistent PATH variables, the per-machine variable and the per-user one.  They get appended together to produce the actual environment variable.  That's why you're getting the path doubled up, you set the per-user variable to include everything from the appended variable.  You can use setx with the /m parameter, but you should consider using [pathman](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657) instead, since it's designed to manipulate paths.  (Using setx can cause data loss if the persistent PATH references another environment variable.)

Comment: @Harry Johnston : the /m param dosn't works me(the problem didn't solved and the link to pathman links to Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools [???]

Comment: yes, pathman is part of the W2003 resource kit tools package.  (You can just download the cab file and extract pathman.exe from it directly, you don't need to run the installer.)

Comment: @Harry Johnston : thank you! it works excellent. (If you want write it as an answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two persistent PATH variables, the per-machine variable and the per-user one. They get appended together to produce the actual environment variable.  (Environment variables in the PATH are also expanded at this point.)

That's why you're getting the path doubled up, because you've set the per-user persistent variable to include everything from the environment variable (which already includes everything from the per-machine persistent one).

You can use setx with the /m parameter to set the per-machine persistent variable, but this isn't ideal:

- If the per-user persistent variable is set, its contents will be copied into the per-machine persistent variable, which is likely to be inappropriate;
- If the persistent variable references other environment variables, the references will be replaced with the current value of those variables.  If the referenced variables change, the PATH will no longer follow those changes.  (To be honest, though, most of the time this won't matter: the feature isn't commonly used.)

Instead, consider using `pathman` which is specifically designed to manipulate paths.  You can get `pathman.exe` from the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657) download.

Note that both `setx` and `pathman` may hang if there are any unresponsive GUI applications running, even if the application window is hidden.  The best way to minimize this risk is to reboot the machine immediately before running any script that uses `setx` or `pathman`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use setx command  with "/m" parameter.

Comment: @Yagel: show the full command line (by editing your question) and tell us what exactly happened.